# how can i get my updated values without performing logout and login operations?

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jsp, servlets

I've working on sign up form and here everything is working fine. But, I have a small problem. When I edit in the form, to values of the form are getting updated inside database. But when I watch my profile, it's still showing the old values only. And then if I try to logout and, again login in the page I'm viewing new values are shown in my profile. So, what might be the problem? How can I get my updated values without performing logout and login operations? thanks in advance..

servlet code for edit details:

```
if(formIdentity.equalsIgnoreCase("editdetails"))
{
    if (checkboxStatus.equalsIgnoreCase("No"))
    {
    User user=new User();
    System.out.println("in datafile con of  servlet...");
         try
         {
         user.setId(Long.parseLong(request.getParameter("userid")));
         user.setFirstName(request.getParameter("fname"));
         user.setLastName(request.getParameter("lname"));
         user.setLocation(request.getParameter("location"));
         user.setDateofbirth(request.getParameter("dob"));
         user.setEmail(request.getParameter("email"));
         user.setDesc(request.getParameter("desc"));
         user.setProfession(request.getParameter("profession"));
         user.setProjects(request.getParameter("myprojects"));  
         user.setHobbies(request.getParameter("hobby"));
         System.out.println("in try con of  servlet...");
         userDao.updateUser(user);
         response.sendRedirect("Home");
         }          
         catch(Exception e1)
         {
        e1.printStackTrace();
         }
         finally
         {
            userDao.closeSession();
         }
         }
         else if(checkboxStatus.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes"))
         {
         mpr=new MultipartRequest(request,webTempPath,5*1024*1024, new MnthFileRenamePolicy());
         response.setContentType("text/html");
         System.out.println("inside editdetails..");
         try
            {
         System.out.println("in datafile con of  servlet...");
         this.filename=mpr.getFilesystemName("datafile");
         File srcFile=new File(webTempPath+this.filename);  
         mpr.copyFile(srcFile, new File(webTempPath+"signup/"+this.filename));
         String imgpath="assets/signup/"+this.filename;
         System.out.println("image is=="+imgpath);
         System.out.println("After file of  servlet...");
         User user=new User();
         user.setId(Long.parseLong(mpr.getParameter("userid")));
         user.setFirstName(mpr.getParameter("fname"));
         System.out.println("After fname of  servlet..."+mpr.getParameter("fname"));
         user.setLastName(mpr.getParameter("lname"));
         user.setLocation(mpr.getParameter("location"));
         user.setDateofbirth(mpr.getParameter("dob"));
         user.setEmail(mpr.getParameter("email"));
         user.setProfession(mpr.getParameter("profession"));
         user.setHobbies(mpr.getParameter("hobby"));
         System.out.println("After email of  servlet..."+mpr.getParameter("email"));
         user.setDesc(mpr.getParameter("desc"));
         user.setImagePath(imgpath);
         userDao.updateUser(user);
         response.sendRedirect("Home");
        }
    catch(Exception e1)
            {
        e1.printStackTrace();
        }
            finally
        {
    userDao.closeSession();
    }
}
```

Comment: from where exactly are you retrieving your profile values?

Comment: hope you arent saving anything in sessions..

Comment: yes i am saving it in sessions.